# Get editing row in kendo grid for angularjs, grid.current is not a function

Tags: angularjs, web, asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid

I'm trying to get current editing row in kendo grid for angularjs.
I tried something like this:

```
var grid = $scope.mainGridOptions;
var dataItem = grid.data(grid.current().closest("tr"));
```

but it didn't work with me, it through an exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: grid.current is not a function
```

I tried this, also didn't work

```
var grid = $scope.mainGridOptions;
 var view = grid.dataSource.view();
  var dataItem = grid.dataSource.data(grid.current);
   console.log(dataItem);
```

Also,

```
var dataItem = grid.dataSource.data((grid.currentTarget).colsest("tr"));
```

error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'colsest' of undefined
```

How can I get current editing row?

ِAny Idea? or Suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 var dataItem = input.get(0).kendoBindingTarget.source;
```